# Talend JSON structure

Tags: json, mongodb, split, tree, talend

I am struggling with my mongodboutput because I can't figure out how to build my JSON tree.
Basically I have this in the "Languages" attribute of my row:

```
Languages##English##fluent##German##beginner##
```

I would like to have :

```
"languages": [
            {
                "language": "English",
                "level": "fluent"
            },
            {
                "language": "German",
                "level": "beginner"
            }
        ]
```

---

I have tried this in a tJavaRow:

```
String delims = "##";
String[] tokens = row3.langues.split(delims);
int i = 0;
while (i < tokens.length) {
    if(i%2==0){
        row5.langue=tokens[i];
    }
    else{
        row5.niveau=tokens[i];
    }
    i++;
}
```

But I only get the last entry in row5 whereas I would like to duplicate the rows

Is it possible to create my own columns in a routine or java component ?

Comment: I tried with tNormalize but I can't associate :
English -> fluent
German -> beginner

Comment: So your question is actually how to parse the string above and convert it to a mongodb document?

Comment: Yes, please see my answer below !

Comment: ??? `row5.langue=tokens[i]` is a plain affectation. Of course, it will overwrite previous value. And as you do that in a loop, you end up only keeping the _last_ value...

Comment: ok thanks for the explanation, do you have any idea how to append the values ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are interrested, I solved this issue by creating my own MongoDBOuput in a tJavaRow.

In this way, I am more able to control the creation of my JSON schema.

For example (in a tJavaRow):

```
/*Get the MongoDB connection*/
DB db = (DB)globalMap.get("db_tMongoDBConnection_1");

/*Get the collection*/
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("cv");

/*Create the JSON object*/
BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject();
doc.append("id", Integer.valueOf(input_row.id));
doc.append("personne", input_row.personne);
doc.append("position", input_row.position);
BasicDBList langues= new BasicDBList();
    String delim="##";
    String[] tokens = input_row.langues.split(delim);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < tokens.length) {
        if(i%2==0){
            res.add(new BasicDBObject("langue",tokens[i]).append("niveau",tokens[i+1]));
        }
        i++;
    }
doc.append("langues", langues);

/*Insert in collection*/
coll.insert(doc);
```

My object in MongoDB :

```
{
    "_id": ObjectID("556da6a905f34ffea3e3dbbe"),
    "id": 1,
    "personne": "Paul Dupont",
    "position": "Consultant BI",
    "age": "23 ans",
    "langues": [
        {
            "langue": "Anglais",
            "niveau": "courant"
        },
        {
            "langue": "Allemand",
            "niveau": "intermediaire"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer. Please delete it and edit your question to add this new information.

Comment: As mentioned previously, this is not an answer. I took the liberty to copy that _verbatim_ to your question. Feel free to edit your *question* further if you need to improve it or to provide some additional details.

Comment: @Jean: Hi Jean, I try to following your code for my custom MongoDBOutput. But I got the ClassCastException said can't be cast MongoDatabaseImpl to DB.
How does your tMongoDBConnection look like? or maybe you know how to fix it. Thanks in advance!